# How to make first and last div fixed in bootstrap collapse?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

Here i want to make panel1 , and panel10 fixed So taht user can see these div in all time . How to do this ?

> I need a solution within one accordion . I can't make 3 accordion to
>   solve this .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div style="height:300px;overflow:scroll;">

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading panel1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Collapsible Group 4</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Collapsible Group5</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">Collapsible Group6</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse7">Collapsible Group 7</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse8">Collapsible Group8</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse9">Collapsible Group 9</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading panel10">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse10">Collapsible Group 10</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse10" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>




  </div>
</div>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I tried position = fixed for these two div , but that time the style is losting.

```
.panel1, .panel10{
position:fixed
}
```

I want to make collapsible 1, and collapsible 10 as fixed. Where collapsible1 is top and collapsible 10 is down .
https://jsfiddle.net/tommisely/75h4d0gf/
Please help.

Comment: Can you add it on jsfiddle or code snippet?

Comment: style is losting means ? its giving error or not working or what ?

Comment: You may move your first and last panel out of the wrapper.

Comment: pleaselook https://jsfiddle.net/tommisely/75h4d0gf/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this one. Link to Fixed header and footer in accordion

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/rizkidwip/75h4d0gf/2/`
```

```css
#accordion1 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#accordion2 {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#accordion3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div style="height:400px;overflow:scroll;">

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading panel1">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end acc1-->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Collapsible Group 4</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Collapsible Group5</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">Collapsible Group6</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse7">Collapsible Group 7</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse8">Collapsible Group8</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse9">Collapsible Group 9</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--end acc2-->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading panel10">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse10">Collapsible Group 10</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse10" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you friend. This answer is working. But the method is not the one i expected . I can't make 3 accordion . I need a solution in one accordion